# I live though I am dead

Tags: riddle

> Four, twenty three, WSD,
>   Surely you know me, though you won't see me.
>
> Since 400 years, you know me as you've read,
>   Since 400 years, I live although I'm dead.

Who or what am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer:

> William Shakespeare

Four, twenty three / Since 400 years

> April 23rd 1616 date of death

WSD

> This is the part I don't understand.  Working on it.  His initials + D?

Comment: Perhaps the D is just for "died"?

Comment: Yes, in fact, April 23 is also WSD, William Shakespeare Day, well done.

Answer (score 3):

You're

> William Shakespeare

Because:
 "Since 400 years, you know me as you've read, since 400 years, I live although I'm dead"

> 2016 - 400 = 1616; 1616 is the year of Shakespeare's death.

"Four, twenty three, WSD, surely you know me."

> Everyone heard at least once of Shakespeare, he was born in [a April 23th](http://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/william-shakespeare-born)  (4, 23) and by googling "shakespeare wsd" yout get links of Weber Disctrict School referencing William Shakespeare.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions Paul Beckingham... I'm new to the site. :|

Comment: I'm new also.  What a fun place it is!